# Layered Navigation - for color and multicolored

Tags: layered-navigation

I like to have in the layered navigation this kind of navigation (see about the colors):

http://www.rei.com/c/womens-shirts?r=c&ir=category%3Awomens-shirts&page=1

What is the easiest way to implement and doing it? We have at the moment all options of colors in one attribute called Color.

How I can do, that I get for example different kind of red in one main color RED.

Answer (score 0):

you can create color attributes:

And assign option to  Color like : Black, Red, Blue, Orange, Green, etc Vendor Color: Elective Blue, Fuzzy Teal, Mystery Yellow, Multi color,etc

Setup the navigation color attribute to do the filtering. 
if you are using RWD as base theme you can use color swatches images as well in navigation side bar sorting.

Comment: This sounds not that bad. So far in theory. And how do I do it in the practice?
I have already Color. But after that I do not know the "next steps".

Comment: http://www.manadev.com/user-guides/general/what-is-layered-navigation-in-magento follow this, i am sure it will work for you